# IllegalArgumentException accessing gallery video URI

Tags: android, kotlin, mediastore

I am trying on Android 11 to display a thumbnail for a video. I have successfully queried the MediaStore and obtained the URIs for pics and videos in the device's gallery. I can display the pics OK, but when I attempt to access the videos to make a thumbnail, I get this error:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: could not access content://media/external/images/media/355
at android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(MediaMetadataRetriever.java:342)

Here is my code:

```
val mmr = MediaMetadataRetriever()
mmr.setDataSource(context, uri)
val bitmap = mmr.getFrameAtTime(1000, MediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST_SYNC);

GlideApp.with(context)
    .load(bitmap)
    .centerCrop()
    .into(view)
```

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a dumb error. My projection was still using most of the fields from the Image projection:

```
val videoProjection = arrayOf(
    MediaStore.Images.Media._ID,
    MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED,
    MediaStore.Images.Media.ORIENTATION,
    MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.DURATION,
    MediaStore.Images.Media.SIZE,
)
```

...whereas it should have been like so:

```
val videoProjection = arrayOf(
    MediaStore.Video.Media._ID,
    MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_ADDED,
    MediaStore.Video.Media.ORIENTATION,
    MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.DURATION,
    MediaStore.Video.Media.SIZE,
)
```

So now the URL is now "content://media/external/videos/media/355", and is readily accessible.